# How can i fix the error: Type Form1' already defines a member called 'Dispose' with the same parameter types?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Tried to change the methods names also tried to create new class and put the code from form1 there but nothing worked.

This is the code in form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using VirtualBox;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Desktop
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        #region DLLs
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateDesktop(string lpszDesktop, IntPtr lpszDevice, IntPtr pDevmode,
                                                   int dwFlags, long dwDesiredAccess, IntPtr lpsa);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SwitchDesktop(IntPtr hDesktop);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "CloseDesktop", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool CloseDesktop(IntPtr handle);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SetThreadDesktop(IntPtr hDesktop);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetThreadDesktop(int dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();
        #endregion

        #region Enumeratoren
        [Flags]
        internal enum DESKTOP_ACCESS_MASK : uint
        {
            DESKTOP_NONE = 0,
            DESKTOP_READOBJECTS = 0x0001,
            DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW = 0x0002,
            DESKTOP_CREATEMENU = 0x0004,
            DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL = 0x0008,
            DESKTOP_JOURNALRECORD = 0x0010,
            DESKTOP_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 0x0020,
            DESKTOP_ENUMERATE = 0x0040,
            DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS = 0x0080,
            DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP = 0x0100,

            GENERIC_ALL = (DESKTOP_READOBJECTS | DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW | DESKTOP_CREATEMENU |
                            DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL | DESKTOP_JOURNALRECORD | DESKTOP_JOURNALPLAYBACK |
                            DESKTOP_ENUMERATE | DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS | DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP),
        }
        #endregion

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Desktop("MyDesktop");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Application.DoEvents();
            Desktop();
            Application.DoEvents();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            SwitchToOrginal();
            Application.DoEvents();
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
            SwitchToOrginal();
            ((IDisposable)this).Dispose();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Unterklassen können hier die Funktionalität der Objektzerstörung erweitern. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fDisposing"></param>
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool fDisposing)
        {
            if (fDisposing)
            {
                // Hier die verwalteten Ressourcen freigeben
                //BspVariable1 = null;
                CloseDesktop(DesktopPtr);
            }
            // Hier die unverwalteten Ressourcen freigeben
        }

        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this); //Fordert das System auf, den Finalizer für das angegebenen Objekt nicht aufzurufen
        }

        #region Variablen
        IntPtr _hOrigDesktop;
        public IntPtr DesktopPtr;
        private string _sMyDesk;
        public string DesktopName
        {
            get
            {
                return (_sMyDesk);
            }
            set
            {
                _sMyDesk = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Konstruktoren
        public void Desktop()
        {
            _sMyDesk = "";
        }

        public void Desktop(string sDesktopName)
        {
            _hOrigDesktop = GetCurrentDesktopPtr();
            _sMyDesk = sDesktopName;
            DesktopPtr = CreateMyDesktop();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methoden
        public void show()
        {
            SetThreadDesktop(DesktopPtr);
            SwitchDesktop(DesktopPtr);
        }

        public void SwitchToOrginal()
        {
            SwitchDesktop(_hOrigDesktop);
            SetThreadDesktop(_hOrigDesktop);
        }

        private IntPtr CreateMyDesktop()
        {
            return CreateDesktop(_sMyDesk, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0, (long)DESKTOP_ACCESS_MASK.GENERIC_ALL, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        public IntPtr GetCurrentDesktopPtr()
        {
            return GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
        }
        #endregion

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

The error is in the form1.designer.cs on this line:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
```

Tried to change the method name here and in form1 but it didn't work.

Comment: What is it that you want to "fix" there is no error, you're trying to implement dispose while it's already done, why are you trying to add your own dispose code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's already a method called Dispose defined, check the designer generated code.

Remove the Dispose from the form1.cs file... Did you notice that public partial class line there? That means the class is spreaded in 2 or more files. So the Dispose is already defined in the form1.designer.cs. So do not create another Dispose, or just remove the "partial" if you really must.

Answer (score 12):

Neel is right it is a partial,

If you need to do some job while dispose you can use some events such as OnDispose, Dispose +=... etc. as well. It is strange that dispose func. is generated automatically in designer file. Even you change designer file it will be generated again.So you can't override this overload method. just you can call it such like this.Dispose(true);...

Use this if you'll dispose something else ,

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Disposed += (s, a) =>
            {
                //Dispose unmanaged stuffs etc.
            };
    }
```

BTW, I've tested after deleting designer.cs method doesn't cause regeneration for Windows Forms app. So it would be possible sol. as well. Mostly most of code generators replace the designer file when things change. Such as EntityCode generators,SL generated codes.

Comment: Messing with the designer is a *really* bad idea, not least because the file will be regenerated even if you change any control on the page by even a single pixel, or press "Save" while the form designer is open. Which is why there is a warning on each designer's header

Comment: Of Course Panagiotis Kanavos, this is what I meant. This is not a right way. I just see that it behaves different for WinForm designers. Quite interesting. There is no run custom tool on right context menu as well. And Forms has no CustomTool set if you look to properties of the cs